# Python regex: Using Alternation for sets of words with delimiter

Tags: python, regex-alternation

I want to match a string for which the string elements should contain specific characters only:

- First character from [A,C,K,M,F]
- Followed by a number (float or integer). Allowed instances: 1,2.5,3.6,9,0,6.3 etc.
- Ending at either of these roman numerals [I, II, III, IV, V].

The regex that I am supplying is the following

`bool(re.match(r'(A|C|K|M|F){1}\d+\.?\d?(I|II|III|IV|V)$', test_str))`

`"(I|II|III|IV|V)"` part will return true for `test_str='C5.3IV'` but I want to make it true even if two of the roman numerals are present at the same time with a delimiter `/` i.e. the regex query should retrun true for `test_str='C5.3IV/V'` also.

How should I modify the regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool(re.match(r'[ACKMF]\d+\.?\d?(I|II|III|IV|V)(/(I|II|III|IV|V))*$', test_str))
```

I also changed the start of your expression from `(A|C|K|M|F){1}` to `[ACKMF]` Characters between square brackets form a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Such a class matches one character out of a range of options. You most commonly see them with ranges like `[A-Z0-9]` to match capital letters or digits, but you can also add individual characters, as I've done for your regex.

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Group the delimiter and the roman numeral and treat it the same way you treat the decimal point in the float / int (you don't know whether or not it will appear but it will only appear once at most). Hope this helps!